# How to pass a PHP variable to a .JS file using JQUERY?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I'm a JQUERY begginner. I'm trying to pass a PHP variable to a js file so that i can use it in JQUERY! But found no resource to learn to do so. I'm able to pass a JQUERY variable to a different php file but I couldn't pass PHP variable to a Jquery file. Is really possible to do so?

**function.php:**

`<?php $variable = $fetch['username']; ?>`

**app.js : How can use this variable in app.js file below?**

$(document).ready(function(){
var flwbtn = $(".findrowpplfollowbtn");

```
flwbtn.click(function(){
    var selectflwusername = $(this).parent().prev().last().find(".findpplrowusername").text();
    
    $.post("../php/flw.php",{flwusernameselected:selectflwusername})
    
});
});
```

Comment: just print it in the script no?..

Comment: Sorry sir i did not understand! Can you explain pls?

Comment: post the script please

Comment: also, in JS you ca use the var keyword to create variables that can be get by all the functions (if declared outside blocks or other context), so you can use `<script> var myvarible = <?php echo $variable = $fetch['username']; ?> <script> ` inside your document head, or at the beginning of the body, and than the other scripts should be able to access it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echo it to HTML temaplate. If it's some structure/array use for example json format.

```
<script>
<?php $variable = $fetch['username']; ?>
var js_variable = <?php echo json_encode($variable); ?>
</script>
```

or
echo some hidden element like

```
<input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value="<?php echo($fetch['username']); ?>">
```

and grab if with Jquery like

```
<script>
$( "#custId" ).value();
</script>
```

with your code
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ var flwbtn = $(".findrowpplfollowbtn");

flwbtn.click(function(){
    var selectflwusername = $(this).parent().prev().last().find(".findpplrowusername").text();

    $.post("../php/flw.php",{$( "#custId" ).value()})

});
});
```

Comment: But I'm using the php in another page!

Comment: you can add some hidden element with id or clas and load it with js?

Comment: I did'nt get it sir!